# netbeans-servlet help

Tags: netbeans6.8

while using netbeans is it necessary to have apache tomcat installed for creating a servlet?

Answer (score 0):

For compiling a basic servlet you need to have the `servlet-api.jar` library added to the classpath and to deploy a servlet you need a [servlet container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container).

> [Apache Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) (or Jakarta Tomcat or
>   simply Tomcat) is an open source
>   servlet container developed by the
>   Apache Software Foundation (ASF).
>   Tomcat implements the Java Servlet and
>   the JavaServer Pages (JSP)
>   specifications from Sun Microsystems,
>   and provides a "pure Java" HTTP web
>   server environment for Java code to
>   run.

[Netbeans 6.8](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/) includes [GlassFish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) which will work as well.